# async array function not catching error - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, try-catch

I cant throw an error properly from a built in async array function, I get the following error - `(node:12104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: non existent item provided`

It is clearly something to do with the fact the error is thrown from within the forEach() async function because if I throw it outside of that function it is caught correctly.

Function:

```
async myFunction(obj) {
    obj.items.forEach(async item => {
        if (itemDict[item]) {
            // do something
        } else {
            throw new Error('non existent item provided');
        }
    });
}
```

Test:

```
describe('type.js', async function() {
    it('throws error if non existent item is provided', async function() {
        try {
            const type = new Type();                
            await type.myFunction({
                items: ['item']
            });
            expect.fail('test failed');
        } catch (err) {
            expect(err.message).to.be.equal('non existent item provided');
        }  
    });
});
```

I have tried wrapping the forEach() in an additional try/catch block but get the same error and the catch block is never triggered.

```
async myFunction(obj) {
    try {
        obj.items.forEach(async item => {
            if (itemDict[item]) {
                // do something
            } else {
                throw new Error('non existent item provided');
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('caught');
    } 
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier It wasn't what I was actually using, I've updated my example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with for loop.

like this:

```
async myFunction(obj) {
    for (const item of obj.items) {
        if (itemDict[item]) {
            // do something
        } else {
            throw new Error('non existent item provided');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked - thanks! But what was wrong with the original implementation?

Comment: forEach does not accept async

Answer (score 1):

Since "forEach" is not asynchronous, there might be lotta problems using async in it. 
If you want to use async in a loop, there is a way of using "for" loop.
Or, even better way, as for me, using async in **map** wrapped in **Promise.all**.

With that one you will perform all of the promises **in parallel** since async function returns **Promise**.

```js
Promise.all(elements.map(async(elem) => elem)));
```

Here is the [link](https://dev.to/jamesliudotcc/how-to-use-async-await-with-map-and-promise-all-1gb5) explaining all of the stuff above.